# How to add time for repeats date with Solspace Calendar

Tags: solspace, plugin-calendar

I using Solspace Calendar on Craft 2. (I can upgrade for Craft 3 soon.)

How to add time for the recurring date?

[image]

My english not so good, sorry.

Thanks your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible at all to set a different time for each recurrance. In that case, you'd have to add each date and time as a separate calendar entry.

Comment: Then there will be more than one of the same content. It does not make sense.

Comment: Or: it is not the same content, if the time is different for each item ;)
Kidding aside, did you ask Solspace about this?

Comment: Paul thanks but same content, diffrent time. look at that : http://dasdas.com.tr/calendar/event/joseph-k